# Rogue "?>" symbols rendering in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I updated views in drupal 7 and am getting rogue "?>" symbols rendering on my pages for regions I created in a zen sub theme.
 The code for one of the regions follows:

```
<!--/#adbanner--> 
<?php if ($page['adbanner']): ?>    
    <div id = "adbanner"  role = "banner">          
           <?php print render($page['adbanner']); ?>        
    </adbanner><!-- /#adbanner--> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If the content that you are rendering came from an external file (or sometimes even an internal one) make sure that the page is saved without the the encoding Marker

Comment: Thanks!I thought of  that and any block I put in that region causes the symbol to be rendered. It was fine until I updated the views module. Even a generic superfish menu causes the problem. The symbol does not show up in any of the original regions from zen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's try to debug this:

Start by deleting all of your content from your files (do it with a *ctrl* + *a*, *ctrl* + *x* and then paste it into a new file - this way we can be sure that ALL of the content is gone). Save the files and render the page.

If the symbols continue to pop up, it is an encoding marker that you will have to turn off. If they stop, it is not an encoding issue and we will have to try something else.

**NOTE:** When I say delete all of the content, make sure that you keep the structure, i.e. the calls to load any external files. Just make sure that the visible content of those files is removed.

Comment: Thank you!  as I looked at the files, I had the div print some text only, no rogue symbol. Then I realized there was also the region--tpl.php for those sections and there it was. Thanks for your help. A stupid rookie mistake that had me chasing my tail for a few hours. D'OH!

Comment: You're welcome! Believe me, we've all been there. Good luck! :)

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept the answer if this helped solve your issue, so as not to leave the question unanswered. :)